# Onclick javascript function doesn't work on first click

Tags: javascript, css

I've wrote a code to hide/show a div by clicking on a "p" element, but at first click nothing happens.
Only from 2nd click the code works as expected.
I've read some similar questions and I've understood that it's probably a style problem.
So I've tried to change style (without really knowing what I was doing) but I wasn't lucky.

I've also another problem: the "p" element sometimes covers an input and I've not understood how to have it on the bottom right of the div but below every other element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        .Class1 {
            position:relative;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 48%;
            margin: 3px;
            border: 3px solid #CCC;  
        }
        .Class2 {
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0;
            right:0;
            border: 1px solid #CCC;
            margin:1px;
            background: #FFC;
        } 
        .Fields {
            clear: both;
            border: 1px solid #CCC;
            display: inline-block;
            margin:3px;
        }
        .H_p {
            border: 1px solid #CCC;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .Opt {
            border: 1px solid #CCC;
            display: none;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>My test</h2>
            <?php 
            $Divs = array('Div1'=>'Class1', 
                'Div2'=>'Class1', 
                'Div3'=>'Class1', 
                'Div4'=>'Class1', 
                'Div5'=>'Class1');
            $AskToShow=array("Field1"=>"1.1.1", "Field2"=>"1.2.1", "Field3"=>"1.3.1");
            foreach ($Divs as $Name=>$Class){
                echo '
                <div class="'.$Class.'">';
                echo $Name.'<br/>';
                foreach ($AskToShow as $I_Name=>$Id){
                    echo '
                        <label>'.$I_Name.'</label>
                            <input type="text" id="'.$Id.'" class="Fields"/>';
                }
                echo '
                    <p id="Btn_Opt'.$Name.'" class="Class2" >Mostra campi opzionali</p>';
                echo '
                        <div id=Opt'.$Name.' name="Opt'.$Name.'" class="Opt" >';
                foreach ($AskToShow as $H_Name=>$Id){
                    echo'
                            <p id="H_'.$Id.'" class="H_p">'.$H_Name.'</p>';
                }
                echo '
                        </div>';
                echo '
                </div>';
            }
            ?>
        <script>
    var MyClass = document.getElementsByClassName("Class2");

    var myFunction = function() {
        var SenderId = this.id;
        var SubId = SenderId.substring(SenderId.indexOf('_')+1)
        var SubSH = document.getElementById(SubId);
        if (SubSH.style.display == 'none'){
            SubSH.style.display = 'inline-block'; 
        }else{
            SubSH.style.display = 'none'; 
        }
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < MyClass.length; i++) {
        MyClass[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
    }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code isn't syntactically correct. And please don't ask two questions in one, try to clean the mess before instead of dumping the raw not working page. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You've got an else statement but no matching if statement ?

Comment: Please discard the php part and fill it with the output of that php script

Comment: @HaukurHaf Sorry: cut-copy mistake

Comment: @Pratansyah I think it should be too much code

Comment: Is it PHP question? If not, don't post PHP code, post generated HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the working code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.Class1 {
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 48%;
    margin: 3px;
    border: 3px solid #CCC;  
}
.Class2 {
    position:relative;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    margin:1px;
    background: #FFC;
    display: inline-block;
    float:right;
} 
.Fields {
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:3px;
}
.H_p {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    display: inline-block;
}
.Opt {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>My test</h2>
<?php
$Divs      = array(
    'Div1' => 'Class1',
    'Div2' => 'Class1',
    'Div3' => 'Class1',
    'Div4' => 'Class1',
    'Div5' => 'Class1'
);
$AskToShow = array(
    "Field1" => "1.1.1",
    "Field2" => "1.2.1",
    "Field3" => "1.3.1"
);
foreach ($Divs as $Name => $Class) {
    echo '
    <div class="' . $Class . '">';
    echo $Name . '<br/>';
    foreach ($AskToShow as $I_Name => $Id) {
        echo '
            <label>' . $I_Name . '</label>
                <input type="text" id="' . $Id . '" class="Fields"/>';
    }

    echo '
            <div id=Opt' . $Name . ' name="Opt' . $Name . '" class="Opt" >';
    foreach ($AskToShow as $H_Name => $Id) {
        echo '
                <p id="H_' . $Id . '" class="H_p">' . $H_Name . '</p>';
    }
    echo '
            </div>';
    echo '
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>';
    echo '
        <p id="Btn_Opt' . $Name . '" class="Class2" >Mostra campi opzionali</p>';
    echo '
    </div>';
}
?>
<script>
    var MyClass = document.getElementsByClassName("Class2");

    var myFunction = function() {
        var SenderId = this.id;
        var SubId = SenderId.substring(SenderId.indexOf('_')+1)
        var SubSH = document.getElementById(SubId);
        if (window.getComputedStyle(SubSH, null).display == 'none'){
                SubSH.style.display = 'inline-block'; 
        } else {
                SubSH.style.display = 'none'; 
        }
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < MyClass.length; i++) {
        MyClass[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So there were two problems
1. **style** property only gives you inline styles. If you want **css styles** + **inline styles**, then you have to use **window.getComputedStyle()**
2. **p** tag needs to moved at the bottom and changed the css styles a little bit to stick at bottom right.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that when you do `SubSH.style.display` you are checking only `inline style` so something which is inn `<your-tag style='...'/>` but you have it in your stylesheet so it is not accessible by this method. try to change your function a bit - for example

```
var myFunction = function() {
    var SenderId = this.id;
    var SubId = SenderId.substring(SenderId.indexOf('_')+1)
    var SubSH = document.getElementById(SubId);
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(SubSH);
    if (style.display == 'none'){
        SubSH.style.display = 'inline-block'; 
    }else{
        SubSH.style.display = 'none'; 
    }
};
```

by using `window.getComputedStyle(SubSH);` you are checking style which is aware of all your classes and csses